# Externally accessing a variable from ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to access an array created in ViewController.m from AppDelegate.m using a method on ViewController. When I try to send the message in AppDelegate.m, XCode gives me the error,

> "No known class method for selector ..."

In ViewController.h:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getButtonArray;
```

In ViewController.m:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getButtonArray;
{
    NSMutableArray *buttonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (ElementButton *button in [self.view subviews]) {
        [buttonArray addObject:button];
    }
    return buttonArray;
}
```

In AppDelegate.m:

```
NSMutableArray *buttonArray = [ViewController getButtonArray];
```

I am not understanding why I cannot call this method on ViewController, as I have declared it in its class files. If this is something that is not allowed for some reason, is there another way to achieve this same effect?

Comment: Just a comment about naming conventions. iOS/Objective C best practices for method names are to name your getters like so: `- (NSMutableArray *)buttonArray;` Setters should be named like: `- (void)setButtonArray:(NSMutableArray *)buttonArray;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getButtonArray` is an instance method. So, you need to create the instance for it.

```
ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *buttonArray = [controller getButtonArray];
```